# Trying to receive a file using a Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, filestream

I'm trying to stream a file over a socket, and write it to a file as I receive it (so that it can be opened in other applications). It mostly works except for near the end where (I'm guessing) it blocks because it's trying to read an entire 8 KB chunk when there isn't that much left to receive. I'm at a loss trying to figure out how to fix this. I know the total amount of bytes I'm supposed to receive, if that helps. Thanks!

```
using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)) {
  socket.Connect(e.IPAddress, e.Port);
  using (var fs = new FileStream(e.Filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read;
    while ((read = socket.Receive(buffer)) > 0) {
      fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[From the MSDN...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available, unless a time-out value was set by using Socket.ReceiveTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Receive call will throw a SocketException. If you are in non-blocking mode, and there is no data available in the in the protocol stack buffer, the Receive method will complete immediately and throw a SocketException. You can use the Available property to determine if data is available for reading. When Available is non-zero, retry the receive operation.

The `Socket.Receive()` method blocks because the connection is still open on the other end, even if there isn't any more data available. There are a couple ways to get around this, one which requres you to know the size of the file beforehand and stopping once you've read that many bytes Another would be using a non-blocking socket (by setting the Socket.Blocking property to false) and getting the data available from the [`Socket.Available`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. The latter requires a little more finesse in writing your code since read operations won't halt your code anymore.

If you know the size of the data beforehand, you can compare that to how much you've read so far and stop once you've reached that size:

```
//If you know the size beforehand, set it as an int and compare
// it to what you have so far
int totalBytes = 9001;

using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
    socket.Connect(e.IPAddress, e.Port);
    using (var fs = new FileStream(e.Filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int read;
        int bytesSoFar = 0; //Use this to keep track of how many bytes have been read

        do
        {
            read = socket.Receive(buffer);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            bytesSoFar += read;

        } while (bytesSoFar < totalBytes);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this second example isn't very robust and will not work when trying to send multiple files using the same socket. But for just a simple 1 file transfer, this should work fine.

Comment: This isn't working, the remote host I'm connecting to is saying it's unable to transfer data due to a broken pipe, so I'm guessing `socket.Available` is returning 0 before it has actually finished, just because it hasn't received any data _yet_. What would the other solution you mentioned look like?

Comment: @Zeffy Gimmie juuust a second to type something up.

Comment: This is yet another misuse of Available. It returns you the number of bytes that can be read *without blocking.* It isn't a general-purpose solution to this question. -1

Comment: @EJP The msdn article on the Receive method was a little misleading, so that's my mistake. I'll remove the example that uses `Available`.

Comment: The new example works perfectly, thank you! All I did was change `do { ... } while (bytesSoFar < totalBytes)` to `do { ... } while (fs.Length < totalBytes)` because it seemed a little redundant, and also because my application needs to support resuming a transfer. But thanks! Marking as answer.

Comment: Your new code will only work if there is no premature EOF. Otherwise your code will loop forever. You need to check 'read' after the receive and before the write.